# Venn5 Diagramm- 5 circles python

Tags: matplotlib-venn, venn

I tried to use the python package matplotlib_venn. venn2 and 3 are working well (with up to 3 circles) but I need to make a plot with 5 circles- for that I wanted to use venn5. I installed the package properly (also tried to deinstall and install again and the most updated version 0.11.9 and also an older version 0.11.5, in case this creates the problem) but in every case I get an error where python tells me "Import Error: cannot import name 'venn5' from 'matplotlib_venn'.
Can somebody maybe help me further here? I don't know anymore what to try! Many thanks

I tried to deinstall and install again and the most updated version 0.11.9 and also an older version 0.11.5, in case this creates the problem. I also tried creating venn plots with up to 3 circles and that worked, but not with 4 and 5.

Comment: I don't think venn-diagrams with more than 3 circles are implemented, as starting with 4 sets, not all possible intersections can be plotted in 2D with circles (or any concave patch for that matter).

Comment: I've seen a package called venn5 or venn5_circles. https://github.com/tctianchi/pyvenn But it always gives me the import error. So I thought it should be possible but i have't figured out yet how.

Comment: matplotlib-venn and pyvenn are separate packages. matplotlib-venn does not implement a class called `venn5`. The full list of implemented classes is: `'venn2', 'venn2_circles', 'venn3', 'venn3_circles', 'venn2_unweighted', 'venn3_unweighted'`.

Comment: ah, thank you very much! I got the error while installing pyvenn, that my computer could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyvenn- do you might have any solution to this? I think that might be the core of my problem.. or do you know a 3D option with matplotlib?

Comment: I am not aware of any implementation in 3D, and fairly certain that there is none. Personally, I would think about alternative ways to visualize set intersections if you have more than 2 or 3 sets. Bipartite graphs come to mind.